# I can not send a post request with Golang?

Tags: go

VBA code works well

```
Set oFields = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
With oFields
    .Add "dor_user", "51"
    .Add "login", "nvivc"
    .Add "pass", "51256"
End With
For Each sName In oFields
    oFields(sName) = sName & "=" & EncodeUriComponent(oFields(sName))
Next
sPayLoad = Join(oFields.Items(), "&")
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "POST", "http://kasant.gvc.oao.rzd:8888/kasant/login?", False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Length", LenB(sPayLoad)
    .Send (sPayLoad)
    Do While .readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
End With
```

Login successful
FIDDLER

> POST http://kasant.gvc.oao.rzd:8888/kasant/login? HTTP/1.1
>
> Accept: */*
>
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> Accept-Language: ru,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
>
> UA-CPU: AMD64
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; Win64;
>   x64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
>
> Host: kasant.gvc.oao.rzd:8888
>
> Content-Length: 34
>
> Connection: Keep-Alive
>
> Pragma: no-cache
>
> Cookie: dor_user=""; kasant_pass=""; kasant_user=""; 
>   kasant_pass_save=false;
>   JSESSIONID=0000VSeSKuzaru0vpwzeeSQF29Y:1ak0n0hlm
>
> dor_user=51&login=nvivc&pass=51256

**JSESSIONID**=0000VSeSKuzaru0vpwzeeSQF29Y:1ak0n0hlm

Code Golang

```
urlLogin := "http://kasant.gvc.oao.rzd:8888/kasant/login?"
formData := url.Values{
    "dor_user": {"51"},
    "login":    {"nvivc"},
    "pass":     {"51256"},
}
client := &http.Client{}
req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", urlLogin, bytes.NewBufferString(formData.Encode()))
req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)")
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
resp, _ := client.Do(req)
defer resp.Body.Close()
```

FIDDLER

> POST http://kasant.gvc.oao.rzd:8888/kasant/login? HTTP/1.1 Host:
>
> kasant.gvc.oao.rzd:8888 User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0;
>
> Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
>
> Content-Length: 34 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip
>
> dor_user=51&login=nvivc&pass=51256

Missing cookies and **JSESSIONID**. Login failed!!! 
Tell me what is the error???

Comment: This example teaches you how to send GET and POST in go. https://dlintw.github.io/gobyexample/public/http-client.html

Comment: You're not setting any cookies in your request, so it isn't sending any. If it needs cookies set, set them: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.AddCookie

Comment: @Adrian JSESSIONID is always different, this value is formed on the server side during each session. Cookies are not listed in VBA code, but everything works fine

Comment: They're probably coming from somewhere else in the VB code (perhaps saved from a previous request to the same site). Cookies don't appear from nowhere.

Comment: @Adrian VB code is written by me, cookies are not registered anywhere in it. Can't the server create them for the session to track authorization

Comment: Yes, cookies originate on the server side. The client gets a `Set-Cookie` header, saves the values, and returns them in the `Cookie` header on subsequent requests. Which means, logically, the first request the client makes to the server will contain no cookies.

Comment: That VBA code might implicitely use IE's cookies or something like that. Go doesn't, of course. Create an HTTP client with a [cookie jar](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Jar) and establish a session before making the login request.

Comment: @Peter thanks for the help, add cookie jar and work well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Peter

```
urlLogin := "http://kasant.gvc.oao.rzd:8888/kasant/login?"
formData := url.Values{
    "dor_user": {"51"},
    "login":    {"nvivc"},
    "pass":     {"51256"},
}
cookieJar, _ := cookiejar.New(nil)
client := &http.Client{
    Jar: cookieJar,
}
respp, _ := client.Post(urlLogin, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", bytes.NewBufferString(formData.Encode()))
defer respp.Body.Close()
```